# Is it possible to limit the set of English locales on a system?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, locale

On Debian and Ubuntu is it possible to limit the locales which have to be configured?

I know that `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` and `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/en` govern which locales are being configured, but short of manually modifying it more or less after the fact (i.e. after an `apt-get dist-upgrade`) I haven't found any method to limit it to `en_US.*` locales as desired.

So whenever the packages `language-pack-en` and `language-pack-en-base` gets touched (and they usually get updated in lockstep, from what I saw), I get something like this:

```
Setting up language-pack-en (1:14.04+20150219) ...
Setting up language-pack-en-base (1:14.04+20150219) ...
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

Unfortunately some upgrades seem to override those two aforementioned files and thus reset modifications I've made to them.

What'd like to see instead is:

```
Setting up language-pack-en (1:14.04+20150219) ...
Setting up language-pack-en-base (1:14.04+20150219) ...
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### With Debian

You can do:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -plow locales
```

### With Ubuntu

The Debian solution doesn't work with Ubuntu, probably because the `locales` package comes from the `langpack-locales` source instead of `glibc` or `eglibc`. But you can choose which `language-pack-*` package to install.

For finer configuration, you might want to modify files under the `/var/lib/locales/supported.d` directory (e.g. `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/en` for `en`-based locales); for instance, you can remove lines corresponding to locales you don't want. Then run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. **Warning**: These files are not *conffiles*, meaning your changes can be overwritten by `dpkg` during package upgrades. You can avoid that by telling `dpkg` to divert overwrites to a different file:

```
cp -a /var/lib/locales/supported.d/en /var/lib/locales/en.upstream
dpkg-divert --local --divert /var/lib/locales/en.upstream --add /var/lib/locales/supported.d/en
```

The diversion code above intentionally puts the diverted file outside the `supported.d` directory because the locale system merges the contents of *all* files in the `supported.d` directory.

Alternatively, you can remove the `language-pack-*` packages that install locales you don't want, and specify additional locales to `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` (using the same format); see the [Ubuntu help on (re-)generating locales](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#A.28Re-.29Generating_locales) for more information. However the `language-pack-*` packages don't just compile locales, but also provide translations, and you may miss them.

Comment: thanks. The latter part is what I was trying to do. Modify those files, but it's not persistent. How can I make my change persist?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Yes, the persistence problem is due to the fact that the `en` file (provided by `language-pack-en-base`) is not a conffile. I've updated my answer to give an alternative way (remove the `language-pack-*` packages), but still with a drawback (perhaps not a problem for English messages).

Comment: thanks a lot. That is a viable option (removal), I guess. As long as I can still use `en_US.*` via the other route.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto the answer by @vinc17 : to prevent `dpkg` from overwriting changes to files like `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/en`, simply use `dpkg-divert`, for example like this:

```
cp -a /var/lib/locales/supported.d/en /var/lib/locales/en.upstream
dpkg-divert --local --divert /var/lib/locales/en.upstream --add /var/lib/locales/supported.d/en
```

Note: The code above intentionally puts the diverted file outside the `supported.d` directory because the locale system merges the contents of *all* files in the `supported.d` directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround.** To prevent changes under `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/`, set files in it with the ["immutable (i)" attribute](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/chattr.1.html). So instead of removing files, empty them. For instance (root privileges are assumed):

```bsh
cd /var/lib/locales/supported.d/
rm <code> && touch <code> # <code> has been emptied
lsattr <code>    # regular attributes
chattr +i <code> # adding (+) immutable
lsattr <code>    # checking attributes
```

Extended details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1281631/762841).

Comment: The reasons of the downvotes would be of help. I believe my answer answers concisely and precisely to the question.

Comment: This will no doubt cause all kind of failures during an upgrade.